# How to Increment Next Record in Django / Templates

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-templates, django-views

In `index.html` - I am able to read the first item of my table / model in Django just fine with my code below.  However, after the user clicks the `next` button - I want it to retrieve the next item of my table / model. (how / where do I build this counter?)

here is views.py

```
def index(request):
  flash_dict = {'flashcards': Card.objects.get(pk=1)}
  return render(request, 'flash/index.html', context=flash_dict)
```

here is index.html

```
      <div class = "jumbotron">
        {% if flashcards %}
          <p class = 'question'>{{ flashcards }}</p>
          <p class = 'answer'>{{ flashcards.flash_answer }}</p>
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" onclick = "flip()">Flip</button>
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Next</button>
          {% else %}
            <p>NO ACCESS RECORDS FOUND!</p>
          {% endif %}
      </div>
```

here is models.py

```
from django.db import models

# Create your models here.

class Card(models.Model):
  flash_question = models.TextField()
  flash_answer = models.TextField()
  objects = models.Manager()

  def __str__(self):
    return self.flash_question
```

here is urls.py (under base project folder)

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include
from flash import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('',views.index,name='index'),
]
```

here is urls.py (under app folder)

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from flash import views

urlpatterns = [
  url(r'^$', views.index, name='index')
]
```

Comment: Could you please share the code of your urls.py file?

Comment: Would also be helpful to have the code of your models.py as well. There are many changes necessary to get your code to work, and easiest to explain if I can access everything.

Comment: @Sam - just updated with the request info - sorry about that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The semantically 'correct' way to make this work is by rewiring your code significantly:

First, you need to modify urls.py, in your base folder, so that the flashcard URL takes a flashcard ID. This will allow you to visit flashcard/1/, flashcard/2/, etc. and see data for the corresponding flashcard.

**urls.py**

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include
from flash import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('flashcard/<int:card>/',views.index,name='flashcard'), # Here we are adding a variable to the URL pattern, which will be passed to the view
]
```

Next, you need to modify your view so that it takes a flashcard ID from the URL and renders the flashcard in question:

**views.py**

```
def flashcard(request, card=1): # Your view will now look for the 'card' variable in your URL pattern.
  flash_dict = {'flashcards': Card.objects.get(pk=card)} # Your 'flashcards' variable now holds the card that corresponds to the ID in the URL
  return render(request, 'flash/index.html', context=flash_dict)
```

Then, we'll write a method within your Card model that will pull the next card when self.get_next is called. Now, if you have a Card object, you can find the next card by calling card.get_next():

**models.py**

```
from django.db import models

# Create your models here.

class Card(models.Model):
  flash_question = models.TextField()
  flash_answer = models.TextField()
  objects = models.Manager()

  def __str__(self):
    return self.flash_question

  def get_next(self):
    next = Card.objects.filter(id__gt=self.id).order_by('id').first()
    if next:
        return next
    # If the current card is the last one, return the first card in the deck
    else:
        return Card.objects.all().order_by('id').first()
```

Finally, we'll replace the buttons in your template with an a href that links to the new 'flashcard' view, and passes it the ID of the next card in the sequence:

**template.html**

```
<div class = "jumbotron">
        {% if flashcards %}
          <p class = 'question'>{{ flashcards }}</p>
          <p class = 'answer'>{{ flashcards.flash_answer }}</p>
          <!-- Here we link to the 'flashcard' view, and pass it the ID of the next card in the sequence -->
          <a href="{% url 'flashcard' flashcards.get_next.id %}">Next flashcard</a>
          {% else %}
            <p>NO ACCESS RECORDS FOUND!</p>
          {% endif %}
      </div>
```

Now, try visiting /flashcard/1 to see how everything works together.